# Is there a way to view overall level XP?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Is there anywhere in/on the interface where it displays your XP until your characters next overall level?

I ask because some skills require you to be a certain level in order to spend skill points in them.  I've looked all over and don't see anything that indicates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't tell you how much XP is needed, I've realized there is an XP bar for overall level on the tab with the hunger and thirst/worn equipment tab.

Comment: in addition i can recommend you some mods to put this (and many other) info on HUD if you playing SP or hosting MP server. If you connecting to others, may be pay attention to Server list and second tab with modded servers.